# Transposing data frame as multiple page document

Tags: r, dataframe, text, sed, r-markdown

Say I have the following data frame:

```
mockdf <- data.frame(firstauthor=c("Jane Doe","John Doe", "John Schmoe"), correspauthor=c("John Smith", "Jenny Jay", "Fulano de Tal"), firstaubio=c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget."), citations=c(1235, 6424, 3211))
```

By using R, how can I "transpose" (if that's the correct term) that into a text document with the following feature:

- **each column name of the data frame should be a field followed by its correspondent value on the same row.**

In that case, using the first 2 entries of the mock data frame, here is the input:

```
   firstauthor correspauthor firstaubio                                                                                                                  citations
1  Jane Doe    John Smith    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 1235                                                                                                                  
2  John Doe    Jenny Jay     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 6424
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
firstauthor: Jane Doe
correspauthor: John Smith
firstaubio: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
citations: 1235

firstauthor: John Doe
correspauthor: Jenny Jay
firstaubio: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
citations: 6424
```

Likely, `dplyr` might do the job, but I am not sure how. I am aware that there might be simpler ways to do this, but if it that can be performed in R, that'd be great! *If not, `sed` command line would also be ok.*

Ultimately I **want to convert the document to a nicely laid out Markdown doc**, where the field names will be subheadings in bold, followed by the correspondent value on the next line. If any of you know a way to already do that, it'll be excellent; however for now, this desired basic structure will do just fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works in Quarto and RMarkdown alike. The idea is to create some code that uses `cat()` to create the formatted output you are trying to achieve. By setting the chunk option `results: asis` we are making sure that the output is interpreted as markdown and `##`/`###` headings are turned into proper sections/headings in the resulting html.

````
---
title: "Literature"
format: html
editor: visual
execute: 
  echo: false
  warning: false
  message: false
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
```


```{r}
mockdf <- data.frame(firstauthor=c("Jane Doe","John Doe", "John Schmoe"), correspauthor=c("John Smith", "Jenny Jay", "Fulano de Tal"), firstaubio=c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget."), citations=c(1235, 6424, 3211))

mockdf$title <- sample(words, 3) # let's add a title for section headers
```

```{r}
#| results: asis
mockdf |> 
  split(1:nrow(mockdf)) |> 
  walk(\(x) {
    cat("##", x$title, "\n\n")
    x_no_title <- select(x, -title)
    iwalk(x_no_title, \(y, i) cat("###", i, "\n\n", y, "\n\n"))
  })
```
````